# Creating dynamic mock request using npm-nock

Tags: node.js, nock

I'm having issues mocking a dynamic url using [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock)

Url I want to mock:
http://example.api.com/svc/Utility.svc/json/GetAPICallRefresh_Module?from=2017-11-25T12:20:50.404Z&module=tennis&languageCode=2

Problem is the `from` parameter which is an ISO timestamp and changing for each API call.

Mock request:

```
nock('http://example.api.com')
    .persist()
    .filteringPath(/from=[^&]*/g, 'module=tennis', 'languageCode=2')
    .get('/svc/Utility.svc/json/GetAPICallRefresh_Module?module=tennis&languageCode=2')
    .reply(200, () => {
        return 'Mock response!'
    });
```

Not working: `Error: Nock: No match for request`
Can you help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` should only contain your path however you have your query string included.

Query string can be matched using the `query` function.

Try this:

```
nock('http://example.api.com')
  .get('/svc/Utility.svc/json/GetAPICallRefresh_Module')
  .query({ module: 'tennis', languageCode: '2' })
  .reply(200, { return 'Mock response!' });
```

Comment: How do we account for the varying `from` url parameter?

Comment: The above example will match anything which has the path `/svc/Utility.svc/json/GetAPICallRefresh_Module` as well as the `module` and `languageCode` query string parameters. The `from` parameter will be ignored and such can be anything - do you need to match it for a specific value?

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks.